# Android M : Billing and GCM permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an app which use GCM and Billing. In order to make it Android M-ready i'm trying to implement the new [permission model](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html).

Unfortunately i can't find any informations about GCM and Billing permissions.
They don't appear in the [normal permission list](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#normal) and are obviously not available with `Manifest.permission.*` because they are not under `android.permission` namespace.

Nevertheless , we still have to declare them in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING">
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE">
```

So how those permissions should be handled ? Are they automatically granted ?

Comment: How strange. I don't see either of those defined when I dump the permissions on an Android 6.0 preview device using `adb shell pm list permissions -g`.

Comment: I think you can go without any problems for these ones.

Comment: Good explanation can be found out-site @[**medium**](https://medium.com/@gabri.mariotti/why-billing-permission-is-not-required-at-runtime-7858a2a56ced#.v7efavjdz).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those permissions are granted automatically at install time:

`checkSelfPermission("com.android.vending.BILLING")` returns `PERMISSION_GRANTED` without ever asking the user.

As far as I understood the documentation and the behaviour of the most recent M preview, the only permissions that have to be requested at runtime are the ones that have a [permission group](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#check-for-permission), since the popups that are prompted to the user only mention permission groups.