# android api 23 user has to grant permission for in app purchase?

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

With the new API 23 - Marshmallow, and the new permission system, the user has to grant his permission for perform an in-app purchase or it is automatically granted?
(Like the "internet" permission e.g.).

Thanks

Comment: What is the specific permission you are interested in? IOW, what is the `<uses-permission>` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission is self granted ones the app gets installed: [Android M : Billing and GCM permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073634/android-m-billing-and-gcm-permissions)

`checkSelfPermission("com.android.vending.BILLING") returns PERMISSION_GRANTED`
without ever asking the user.